# Automatic input sum with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a calculation of more fields and I would like to get the #price + # price2 automatic sum without any jQuery event.
I've been looking for a variety of tutorials but I just managed to get the sum with the click.

I would like her without the click, how can she do it?

```js
function calcscore() {
  score = 0;
  $(".calc:checked,#TextBox4").each(function() {
    score += Number($(this).val());
  });

  $("#sum").val(score)
  $("#price").text(score.toFixed(2));
}

function add() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".test").each(function() {
    sum += +this.value;
  });
  return sum; // an add function shouldn't really "alert"
}


$(document).on("change", ".test", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".test").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $("#price3").val(sum);
});


$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".calc").change(function() {
    calcscore();
  });

  $('#add').click(function() {
    $("#price3").text(add().toFixed(2));
  });

  $("#TextBox1").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M',
    altField: "#arrivo",
    altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
      var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
      $("#TextBox2").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0'); // Set other min, default to today
    }
  });

  $("#TextBox2").datepicker({
    minDate: '0',
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M',
    altField: "#partenza",
    altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
      var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
      $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', max || '+1Y+6M'); // Set other max, default to + 18 months
      var start = $("#TextBox1").datepicker("getDate");
      var end = $("#TextBox2").datepicker("getDate");
      var timeDiff = Math.abs((end - start));
      var days = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

      $("#TextBox3").val(days);

      if (days == 1) {
        parseInt($("#TextBox4").val('10'), 10);
        parseInt($("#price2").text('10'), 10);

      } else if (days == 0) {
        parseInt($("#TextBox4").val('10'), 10);
        parseInt($("#price2").text('10'), 10);
        $("#TextBox3").val('1');
      } else if (days == 2) {
        parseInt($("#TextBox4").val('12'), 10);
        parseInt($("#price2").text('12'), 10);
      } else if (days == 3) {
        parseInt($("#TextBox4").val('14'), 10);
        parseInt($("#price2").text('14'), 10);
      } else if (days == 4) {
        parseInt($("#TextBox4").val('16'), 10);
        parseInt($("#price2").text('16'), 10);
      } else if (days >= 5) {
        var y = (days) * 4;
        parseInt($("#TextBox4").val(y), 10);
        parseInt($("#price2").text(y), 10);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="tipo-veicolo">
    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="type" value="5"> Macchina
    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="type" value="2"> Scooter
    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="type" value="10"> Camion
  </div>
  <div class="variant">
    <label>Cambio olio</label>
    <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" value="10" />
    <label>Cambio gomme</label>
    <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check2" value="2" />
    <label>Car valet</label>
    <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check3" value="12" />
  </div>
  <div id="selezione-data">
    <div class="check-in">
      <label>Check-In</label>
      <input type="text" id="TextBox1" />
    </div>
    <div class="check-out">
      <label>Check-Out</label>
      <input type="text" id="TextBox2" />
    </div>
    <div class="numero-giorni">
      <label>Numero Giorni</label>
      <input type="text" id="TextBox3" value="0" />
      <label>Arrivo</label>
      <input type="text" id="arrivo" size="30">
      <label>Partenza</label>
      <input type="text" id="partenza" size="30">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="totale">
    <input class="test num1" name="totale" id="TextBox4" value="0" />
    <input class="test num2" type="text" name="sum" id="sum" value="0"> Sum: <input type="text" class="sum" readonly="readonly">
  </div>

</form>

<p>Total: PHP <span id="price">0</span></p>

<p>Total: PHP <span id="price2">0</span></p>

<p>Total: PHP <span id="price3">0</span></p>

<input id="add" type="button" value="add" />
```

Thank you and good day

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can't do it without using any events.

You can achive automatic aggregation by using, for example, **input event** in jQuery.

Here is example of this:

```
$('.num1, .num2').on('input', function () {
    $('.sum').val(parseInt($('.num1').val()) + parseInt($('.num2').val()));
});
```

[Here is jfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fvtofpjs/4/)

Comment: Inputs are given from date selection and check

Answer (score 0):

Try this to achieve your goal, place it the end of `document.ready` event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
..
..
..
   $("input").change(function() { // place it at the bottom of other events, this will listen for all inputs
     $("#price3").text(add().toFixed(2)); // after input changes it will calculate
   });
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2kjLjxpb/)

Hope helps,